# Parallel vector and dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, inner-products

I'm trying to show that $\|u\cdot v\|= \|u\| \, \|v\| \iff u = \alpha v, \quad \alpha\in \mathbb{R}$.

$(\Leftarrow)\;$ Note that
$\|\alpha v\cdot v\| 
= |\alpha| \, \| v\cdot v\| 
= |\alpha| \, \| (\sum_{k=1}^n v_k^2)\| 
= |\alpha| \, \sum_{k=1}^n v_k^2$.
Also, $\|v\| = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n v_k^2}$, so
$\|u\| = \|\alpha v\| = |\alpha| \, \|v\| = |\alpha| \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n v_k^2}$.

Therefore, $\|u\cdot v\| \, 
= |\alpha| \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n v_k^2} \, \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n v_k^2} 
= |\alpha| \sum_{k=1}^n v_k^2 
= |\alpha| \, \|v \cdot v\| 
= \|\alpha v \cdot v\|$.

$(\Rightarrow)\;$ We see that
$\|u \cdot v\| 
= \bigl\| \sum_{k=1}^n {u_k v_k} \bigr\| 
= \bigl| \sum_{k=1}^n {u_k v_k} \bigr|, 
\qquad \|u\| = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n u_k^2}, 
\qquad \|v\| = \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n v_k^2}$.

Then $\|u\| \, \|v\| 
= \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n u_k^2} \, \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n v_k^2} 
= \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n u_k^2 \, \sum_{k=1}^n v_k^2} 
= \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^n u_k^2 \, v_k^2}$.

I got stuck at this point trying to show that
$\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n u_k^2} \, \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n v_k^2} 
= \bigl| \sum_{k=1}^n {u_k v_k} \bigr|$.

Can someone lend me a hand, please?

Comment: Trivial:  $\| u \cdot v \| = \|u \| \ \| v \| \cos \theta$... and therefore....

Comment: Whoa. That was trivial indeed. I just was not using the known facts, thanks! BTW, is the first part well justified (just wanna make sure to be on the safe side)?

Comment: Note: use `\| v \|` for better formatted norm bars: $\| v \|$.

Comment: If you don't want to use the cosine formula, you can walk through the proof of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and examine what conditions would lead to equality. This is discussed in the last paragraph of this [Wikipedia subsection with the proof of the inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality#For_real_inner_product_spaces).

Comment: Yet another way without the cosine formula: assume WLOG $\,\|v\|=1\,$ by homogeneity of the relations, then $\|u - (u \cdot v) v\|^2=\|u\|^2+ (u \cdot v)^2 \|v\|^2 - 2 (u \cdot v)^2 = \|u\|^2 - (u \cdot v)^2 = 0$ $\implies u = \underbrace{(u\cdot v)}_{\alpha} v\,$.

Comment: Note that $\|u\cdot v\|$ is wrong. This should be $|u\cdot v|$.